# How to determine + key down?

Tags: jquery, cross-platform

Using jQuery, how do I determine that user has pressed '+'. I know that by matching keycode in the keydown event is the way to go, but that is apparently not cross platform. Since, the keycodes vary in Linux OS. Matching to charcode is also not an option because it is not cross browser. IE, of course, does not support charcode.

Does anyone know a cross platform solution to do this? Google+ has apparently been able to achieve this.

Comment: please do not tag it PHP when you are asking about jquery

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it works in Windows and Mac but not in Linux!

Comment: Post some code. What keycode gets returned in linux?

Comment: The downvote was for a) not posting code and b) not being clear if you had tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#element").keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 61 || e.keyCode == 107){ // 61 for windows, 107 for mac
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

or, if you feel this isn't reliable, use

```
if ($.firefox){
   var keycode = ..;
}

if ($.opera){
    var keycode = ..;
}
// and more
```

where you have to change .. with certain keycode working in that browser